# How to correct the font of a web page in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I do not know what happened with my chrome, but fonts are horrible on some pages.

For example, consider the following page - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/_migrating_to_the_beats_input_plugin_for_logstash.html. This is how it looks like on my Chrome:
[image]

Compare to IE:
[image]

I went to the font settings in Chrome and here are they:
[image]

So, I am at loss - what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify our Chrome version ?
Maybe one of them will work:

1. Empty your cache
2. Reset the Chrome Settings
3. Reinstall

Comment: Checking the version told me "Almost there" and asked to relaunch. I relaunched and voila - it renders OK now. Thanks for leading me to the version screen. So simple at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try to launch an anonymous session to verify that cache or extension are not involved in this bad font rendering.

If it does not work try to disable LCD text antialiasing in your Chrome settings: [chrome://flags/](http://chrome://flags/)

[image]